# invalid syntax in function definition I'm trying to create a Python function to sort and list candidates from an Excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, list, sorting

Getting a syntax error while using sort&list function in python code

```
import pandas as pd

def sort_and_list_candidates('C:\Users\Sonu Priya R\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Project\Candidates.xlsx', 'Candidates', sort_by_column='Name', ascending=True):
    try:
        
        df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Sonu Priya R\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Project\Candidates.xlsx', 'Candidates')
        
        
        sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=sort_by_column, ascending=ascending)
        
    
        print(sorted_df)
        
        return sorted_df
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


file_path = r"C:\Users\Sonu Priya R\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Project\Candidates.xlsx"
sheet_name = 'Candidates'

sorted_candidates = sort_and_list_candidates('C:\Users\Sonu Priya R\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Project\Candidates.xlsx', 'Candidates', sort_by_column='work_experience', ascending=True)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you told us exactly where the issue is... And what you've tried to solve it

Comment: Please [edit] post with exact error message or describe undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

Python function definitions accept variables, with optional defaults. They cannot accept just strings

You're hard-coding the first two parameters in the function body anyway, so you should remove them, or otherwise fix them to be properly passed in

In other words, where are you actually using `file_path` variable outside of a print statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have literal strings in the parameter definition of a function.

You have to use *variable names*, like so:

```
def sort_and_list_candidates(xlsfile, title, sort_by_column='Name', ascending=True):
```

Then, inside the function, you can refer to those variables:

```
    df = pd.read_excel(xlsfile, title)
```

When you *call* the function, you can use the literal strings, just as you were.

```
sorted_candidates = sort_and_list_candidates('C:\Users\Sonu Priya R\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Project\Candidates.xlsx', 'Candidates', sort_by_column='work_experience', ascending=True)
```

The literal strings will be passed as the value of those variables.